# Unity, Sprite textures don't load when pushed on github

Tags: unity-game-engine, github

I'm actually working on a Unity project and I'm using Github.
I decided to do again the menu of the game but when I switch computer to work again on the project I got some issues with it.

[image]

As you can see a big part of my Sprites and Fonts don't load. When i set back the menu by putting Sprite textures to Sprite (2D and UI) and adding the component it works well. But when I push the modification and pull to another computer, the same problem happen. The Sprites textures are back to default :
[image]

All the other sprites or prefab are working well so I don't understand.

Version : 2021.3.4f1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure you are using `VisibleMetaFiles` in `ProjectSettings -> Version Control -> Mode`
- Make sure that the metafile for the texture with issues is not corrupted and is under version control (it will be right near your texture with the same name and the `.meta` extension)
- Check the history of this metafile to make sure that it is really pushed to the repo and then downloaded from there

Import settings for the texture are stored in this metafile, so you need to make sure that it shares correctly between two computers

Comment: Yeah you right thank you I fixed the problem like 2 minutes ago, it was from my .gitignore. I add a *.meta like 2 weeks ago to test something on the repo but i forgot to delete it so every time I pushed it didn't count meta modifications...